# See Firebase Test Lab Usage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, billing, firebase-test-lab

Normally, you can see under "Usage and billing" the usage of all Firebase Services. We have integrated integration test with Firebase Test Lab into our CI. Now I want to know how much usage we use and when do we need to pay for our usage.

Is there any view in Firebase or Google Cloud Platform to the use Firebase Test Lab usage of the current project?

[image: Firebase Usage Tab]

Comment: This depends on your setup, do you have the test lab on an independent project, or is it part of your general project? Also, you can get the granularity of the services, but you don't get further granularity. However, you can get an estimate through the gcp billing calculator:

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are currently using the Firebase Spark free tier? On that plan you may run tests on 10 virtual devices and 5 physical devices each day.

If you're using the Blaze pay-as-you-go plan, you can see Test Lab device usage in the Cloud Console. Start at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing and select your project and billing plan. From there you can view usage graphs and generate billing reports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We have the Blaze Plan. So we should have 60 minutes for virtual devices. My goal is to see how many minutes we spend per day, to see how big is our usage. In the billing section of GCP I can only see that Firebase Test Lab costs us €0.00. But I can't see how many minutes of the free trier we are using per day. I'm searching for a view where we see something like 23/60 minutes used.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a great answer for your request. Under the Blaze plan, the Cloud Billing section only reports your actual billed time (i.e. just the device usage after you consume your daily free minutes). 

The test results page(s) in the Firebase Console do list the device time used by each test execution, but you'd have to manually add those up for a given day.